# Why is there no runConst function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a convention so that I know when to expect `runX` versus `getX` typeclass functions?

Comment: As far as I know, this is an inconsistency with no rationale behind it.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean [this](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.1/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const) `Const`? Why would you expect there to be a `runConst` function? What type would it have? Or would you expect `getConst` to be named `runConst`? There is no convention as to what a record selector should be named (except, perhaps, that it should reflect somehow the semantics of the field). (Aside: these are not typeclass function)

Comment: I don't know of a convention, but I usually imagine `runX` to *do* something (like execute/return a function or return a monadic action), and then `getX` to *extract* something. `runConst` wouldn't make too much sense as a name, given that it's just unboxing a value.

Comment: Another common variant to add to the confusion is `unX`.

Comment: @4castle, sure, but we have `runIdentity`, which is an extractor if ever there was one. BTW, I wouldn't call this "unboxing"; that has a rather different meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's purely a matter of how the author preferred to think about what they're representing. And it's often more about the "abstract concept" being represented, not the actual data structure being used to represent it.

If you have some type `X` and think of an `X` value as a *computation* that could be run to get a value, then you'd have a `runX` function. If you think of it as more like a *container*, then you'd have a `getX` function (There are other possible interpretations that could lead to `runX` or `getX` or something else, these are just 2 commonly recurring ways of thinking about values).

Of course when we're using first class Haskell values to represent things (and functions are perfectly good values), a lot of the time you could interpret something as either a computation or a container reasonably well. Consider `State` for representing stateful computations; *surely* that has to be interpreted as a computation, right? We say `runState :: State s a -> s -> (a , s)` because we think of it as "running" the `State s a`, needing an `s` as additional input. But we could just as easily think of it as "getting" an `s -> (a, s)` out of the `State s a` - treating `State` more like a container.

So the choice between `runX` and `getX` isn't really meaningful in any profound tense, but it tells you how the author was thinking about `X` (and perhaps how they think you should think about it).

`Const` is so-named in analogy to the function `const` (which takes an argument to produce the "constant function" that takes another input, ignores it, and returns whatever the first input to `const` was). But it's thought of as operating at the *type* level; `Const` takes a *type* and generates a "type-level function" that ignores whatever type it is applied to and then is isomorphic to the first type `Const` was applied to. Isomorphic rather than equal because to create a new type that could have different instances, it needs to have a constructor. At the *value* level, in order to be an isomorphism you need to be able to get a `Const a b` from an `a` (that's the `Const` constructor), and get the `a` back out of a `Const a b`. Since "being isomorphic to `a`" is *all* the properties we need it to have there's no real need to think of it as doing anything other than being a simple container of `a`, so we have `getConst`.

`Identity` seems similarly obvious as "just a container" and we have `runIdentity`. But one of the main motivations for having `Identity` is to think of `Identity a` as being a "monadic computation" in the same way that `State s a`, `Reader e a`, etc values are. So to continue the analogy we think of `Identity` as a "do-nothing" computation we *run*, rather than a simple wrapper container that we get a value out of. It *would* be perfectly valid to think of `Identity` as a container (the simplest possible one), but that wasn't the interpretation the authors chose to focus on.